# What's the best way to do a "couple" system in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm programming a RPG website with Rails 3.1 and I've got a User model (fields don't matter much).

What I need is to be able to marry two users but I don't know what's the best way for the associations.

I've thought of user1 and user2 as columns but I don't know how to say that both are the same when associating it to the User model in order to know whether a User is married or not. (that's to say that a user id can be on one column or the other one...)

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's always one to one you could set it up like this:

```
class User
  belongs_to :partner, :foreign_key => :partner_id, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :partner
end
```

Which should handle the inverse relationship as well, e.g.

```
user_1.partner = user_2
user_2.partner # <user_1>
```

If you need `Marriage` as a class, the marriage could just relate to users through `has_many` and validate that the # of users is 2 (if it's a traditional marriage).  E.g. if you went the STI route:

```
class Marriage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :marriage
end

class TraditionalMarriage < Marriage
  validate do |record|
    if record.users.length != 2
      record.errors.add(:users, "Marriage is between 2 people!!")
    end
  end
end

class PartyTimeMarriage < Marriage
  validate do |record|
    if record.users.length < 3
      record.errors.add(:users, "A good marriage requires at least three spouses!!")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this will work but you'll lose `Marriage` as an external class.  Marriage as an external class will still work if the marriage `has_many` users but validates that that number is 2.

Comment: +1 first time I have seen inverse, nice, had to google it - http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to

Comment: Does the inverse_of still work? I just tried it in my user class: `belongs_to :spouse, :foreign_key => :spouse_id, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :spouse` and `u.spouse = u1 #works!` but `u1.spouse` is still nil.

Answer (score 1):

Some form of

```
has_one :wife, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :husband, :class_name => "User"
```

should work in your User active record model. Maybe slap on some validation for genders.

Another solution would be to create a married table with 2 User references (has_one), to hold additional data like marriage date and stuff.

Comment: this is of course assuming that same sex marriage is barred in this fantasy universe

Comment: Yeah I want an external table ;) (In order to hold couples, marriages and so on...)

Answer (score 1):

this is untested, but worth experimenting with

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :spouse, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'spouse_id' 

    def get_married_to(user)
        self.spouse = user
        user.spouse = self
    end
end

u1 = User.new
u2 = User.new
u1.get_married_to(u2)
```

also check out the rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html